# One file executable generation with custom modified spec file in PyInstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have a heavily modified spec file which I would like to compile using the `--onefile` option. I have several hidden imports and file path extensions but of course the standard `Analysis`, `PYZ`, `EXE` and `COLLECT` objects are still in there.

When I compile the `.py` file and allow `pyinstaller` to generate a spec file for me, using the `--onefile` option works and I do get one file executable.

When i compile my own `.spec` file with the `--onefile` option, `pyinstaller` fails to bundle everything up into one file. As far as I can tell it makes no difference, when using my own `.spec` file, whether I provide the `--onefile` option or now.

How can I compile my program into a one file executable, where I am providing my own `.spec` file?